# Real time updates in a Django template

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, heroku, websocket

I have a django webapp that displays stock data.

**How it works**:

I make requests to a stock data API and get data every 15 mins when the US stock market is open. This is a background periodic task using Celery.

I have a database where I update this data as soon as I get it from the API.

Then I send the updated data from the database to a view, where I can visualize it in a HTML table.

Using jQuery I refresh the table every 5mins to give it a feel of "real time", although it is not.

My goal is to get the HTML table updated (or item by item) as soon as the database gets updated too, making it 100% real time.

The website will have registered users (up to 2500-5000 users) that will be visualizing this data at the same time.

I have googled around and didn't find much info. There's django channels (websockets), but all the tutorials I've seen are focused on building real time chats. I'm not sure how efficient websockets are since I have zero experience with them.

The website is hosted on Heroku Hobby for what its worth.

My **goal** is to make a fully real time webapp and make is as much efficient as possible.

Comment: What exactly is the problem if all code is working? reduce refresh time of jquery from 5 minutes to few seconds and probably reduce the API calling time from 15 minutes too.

Comment: The API calling time is fine. The problem is the 5min jQuery refresh time. I thought about reducing it to 10secs but if I have 2000 users viewing the template thats 12000 get requests per minute. Wouldn't that be too many get requests per minute? I'm new to this and my concern is overloading the server with that

Comment: Heroku Hobby is probably not best choice for "what its worth" if its gonna have 2500 users active at a time

Comment: Yeah I am using hobby just to test. I will upgrade once I'm satisfied with the app

Comment: Django will scale jquery too for that many users and that many requests if you have a good server, dont worry about that. However looking into django channels with websockets can be a good option.